# Spring Scheduled метод не запускается никогда

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть метод помеченный аннотацией Scheduled, который запускается по cron выражению @Scheduled(cron = "${archive.cron}"). Свойство archive.cron указывается в конфигурационном файле. Я хочу добавить в аннотацию значение "по умолчанию", при котором этот метод не запустится никогда. Мой вопрос о том какое значение написать?

Comment: Вот тут пишут (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13836907/3212712), что можно дату в будущем поставить. Типа `59 59 23 31 12 ? 2099`